# Pipelet Input Parameter missing

Tags: pipeline, intershop

This is my code

[Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1S7Y.png)

[Pipelets java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t9ut.png)

[Pipelets XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNPOV.png)

I'm passing a parameter(SKUs) value into a pipeline from js.
The value is getting passed into the pipeline but not into pipelets.
It gives me parameter `SKUs` in not available.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to pass a String to a List. You could try again by making Pipelet Input Parameter "SKUs" type "java.util.List<java.util.String>".

Comment: have tried this "java.util.List<java.util.String>" but didn't help, though from js I' sending this value as String with comma separated now when I get the value into the pipelet I have again done split and created a list

Answer (score 1):

If your SKUs parameter is passed to the pipeline using JS client (via post or get), your pipelet needs to process type `String[]`.

Comment: It is passed as a string and inside the piplet I have accepted the string and then later I have created a list using this string